# Unable to get select box filter to work using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was following the example fiddle seen here https://jsfiddle.net/cqDES/

and attempting to amend it to meet my needs which is seen here https://jsfiddle.net/rLe6q9vg/3/

I'm not able to replicate the code correctly though, when I click the select button, i dont see the correct div displayed with the content "Activity" or "Friend"

Not understanding what I have missed?

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            $('div:not(#ActivityBadge' + val + ')').slideUp();
            $('#ActivityBadge' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('div').slideDown();
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

```
            <select name="huge" class="btn-group select select-block mbl select-multiple" id="options">
                    <option value="0">Click to filter notifications</option>
                    <option value="1">Activity Notifications</option>
                    <option value="2">Friends Notifications</option>
                </select>

            <div id="ActivityBadge" class="containerB">badge</div>
            <div id="ActivityFriends" class="containerF">friends</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select values has to match the ids of the divs. The divs have to have a content. https://jsfiddle.net/83y0t0rm/

```
<select name="huge" class="btn-group select select-block mbl select-multiple" id="options">
    <option value="">Click to filter notifications</option>
    <option value="ActivityBadge">kudosoo Notifications</option>
    <option value="ActivityFriends">Friends Notifications</option>
</select>
<div id="ActivityBadge" class="containerB" ACTIVITY>badge</div>
<div id="ActivityFriends" class="containerF" FRIEND 1>friends</div>

$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            $('div:not(#' + val + ')').slideUp();
            $('#' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('div').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I see... just checking the fiddle, the select box doesn't update the div content displayed though? both remain visible on the page after I click select box option, it should remove either friends or activity depending whats been clicked

Comment: my browser ie11 shows a security issue, if forced to display all content, it may work.